# YUI3 How to see if an element exists

Tags: javascript, css, yui3

How would I tell if an element exists in YUI3?

For example if `#noHero` exists then add a class name to `#header`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking for the existence of a single node using `Y.one()`, the then following will work:

```
var el = Y.one("#noHero");

if (el) {
  // do something
}
```

However, it's worth noting that `Y.all()` will return an empty `NodeList` which will evaluate as true. In this case, you should use `.size()` as your test condition.

```
var els = Y.all(".noHero");

if (els.size()) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/hwf72/6/)

```
function findThis() {
    return Y.one("#noHero");
}

if (findThis()) {
   alert("found");
}
else{
  alert('not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using in this way

```
var mainDiv =Y.one("#noHero");

if ( mainDiv ) {
    mainDiv.addClass(".someClass");
}
```

In the above statement if the YUI cannot find a node than it would return "null" which is always false